# Understanding a type assigning when using generics methods/types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build a generic type that will accept when initializing an instance of type T1 and accept an instance of type T2 in its methods.
So, now I have a generic method, where acceptable types have a convention - to be a child of some abstract class, and I have internal collection of this abstract type instances:

```
private readonly IList<Tuple<CommandBase<SocialNetworkUnit, SocialNetworkUnit>, SocialNetworkUnit>> _history;

public bool Invoke<TInitiator, TParameter>(CommandBase<TInitiator, TParameter> command, TParameter parameter)
    where TInitiator : SocialNetworkUnit
    where TParameter : SocialNetworkUnit
{
    var success = command.Run(parameter);
    this._history.Add(new Tuple<CommandBase<SocialNetworkUnit, SocialNetworkUnit>, SocialNetworkUnit>(command, parameter));
}
```

But I have a compilation error said that TInitiator- and TParameter- parameters (conventioned to SocialNetworkUnit) cannot be used for  collection.

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CommandUnits.CommandBase<TInitiator,TParameter>' to 'CommandUnits.CommandBase<Command.SNUnit.SocialNetworkUnit,Command.SNUnit.SocialNetworkUnit>'
```

Can you show me my mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CommandBase` isn't covariant with respect to these two generic arguments.  It would need to be covariant for that to work, and in C# classes cannot be covariant, only interfaces can be.  If you create an interface that has both of these generic arguments as being covariant, and use that interface instead of `CommandBase` in the list that you have, then the code would be able to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try an explicit cast:

```
this._history.Add(new Tuple<CommandBase<SocialNetworkUnit, SocialNetworkUnit>, SocialNetworkUnit>(command as CommandBase<SocialNetworkUnit, SocialNetworkUnit>, parameter));
```

Comment: This will just make it fail at runtime.  (Or simply make it always be `null`, because you incorrectly used `as`.)